# Is there a way to speed up HTML to NSAttributedString rendering in iOS 8?

Tags: html, ios, objective-c, ios7, ios8

I may be wrong, but it seems *a lot* slower than it was in iOS 7. It's all but unusable in production with iOS 8.

The following line:

```
NSString *htmlString = @"<em>emphasis</em> with some <strong>bolder text</strong>";
[[NSAttributedString alloc] initWithData:[htmlString dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding] options:@{NSDocumentTypeDocumentAttribute: NSHTMLTextDocumentType, NSCharacterEncodingDocumentAttribute: @(NSUTF8StringEncoding)} documentAttributes:nil error:nil];
```

Takes **0.48 seconds** to execute. Half a second to parse two simple HTML tags.

But I'm wondering if there's something weird going on, as if I use the HTML string:

```
NSString *htmlString = @"<em>emphasis</em> with some <strong>bolder text</strong> and <a href='http://google.ca'>google</a> with some <sup>superscript</sup> and some <sub>subscript</sub> and a <h1>header</h1> followed by some <strong><em>nested bold and italics</em></strong> plus some <em>neato</em> and some more <a href='#'>well then</a> with a bit of <del>strikethrough</del> and other text <em>emphasis</em> with some <strong>bolder text</strong> and <a href='http://google.ca'>google</a> with some <sup>superscript</sup> and some <sub>subscript</sub> and a <h1>header</h1> followed by some <strong><em>nested bold and italics</em></strong> plus some <em>neato</em> and some more <a href='#'>well then</a> with a bit of <del>strikethrough</del> and other text <em>emphasis</em> with some <strong>bolder text</strong> and <a href='http://google.ca'>google</a> with some <sup>superscript</sup> and some <sub>subscript</sub> and a <h1>header</h1> followed by some <strong><em>nested bold and italics</em></strong> plus some <em>neato</em> and some more <a href='#'>well then</a> with a bit of <del>strikethrough</del> and other text <em>emphasis</em> with some <strong>bolder text</strong> and <a href='http://google.ca'>google</a> with some <sup>superscript</sup> and some <sub>subscript</sub> and a <h1>header</h1> followed by some <strong><em>nested bold and italics</em></strong> plus some <em>neato</em> and some more <a href='#'>well then</a> with a bit of <del>strikethrough</del> and other text <em>emphasis</em> with some <strong>bolder text</strong> and <a href='http://google.ca'>google</a> with some <sup>superscript</sup> and some <sub>subscript</sub> and a <h1>header</h1> followed by some <strong><em>nested bold and italics</em></strong> plus some <em>neato</em> and some more <a href='#'>well then</a> with a bit of <del>strikethrough</del> and other text";
```

Which is an HTML string **33x** longer, and it takes **0.51 seconds**.

So the string is **33x longer** but takes only **1.06** times longer (or 0.03 seconds longer) to render.

Is there just an absurd startup time I can mitigate somehow? This seems like it's taking a very unreasonable amount of time to render, whereas in iOS 7 I could almost remember it being instantaneous.

<sub>If not, any recommendations for an alternative HTML to NSAttributedString solution?</sub>

Comment: it's unclear to me from the documentation: `The HTML importer should not be called from a background thread (that is, the options dictionary includes NSDocumentTypeDocumentAttribute with a value of NSHTMLTextDocumentType).` Does specifying those dictionary values place it on a background thread, or the main thread?

Answer (score 1):

Converting text from HTML to NSAttributedText using built-in framework unfortunately has unacceptable performance. You should look into using 3rd party libraries, like DCCoreText.

https://github.com/Cocoanetics/DTCoreText

Comment: Seems so, `DTCoreText` did the longer example in **0.0285 seconds**, about 18x quicker. Would have liked to have used a system function, but oh well.

Comment: We did a performance comparison for our project and ended up using DCCoreText.

Comment: Had to render 500+ tableview cells with HTML markup just as it needed to be displayed, which broke scrolling. Switched to DTCoreText, solved that problem. Apple engineers at WWDC 2017 pretty much just told me "yeah, no one uses this for HTML anymore, don't know why it's broken"